# Slow while assigning Bitmap to ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

It is taking time when i tried to change the bitmap.
Setting a new bitmap into an ImageView can also be cause of slowdown since you're updating the image frequently.

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("videofilepath", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
image.setImageBitmap(thumb);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);
```

Comment: but it is not happening when i frequently change the bitmap created using utility class

Comment: Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("videofilepath", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
image.setImageBitmap(thumb);
Bitmap thumb2 = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("videofilepath2", MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
image.setImageBitmap(thumb2);
This issue happens only when i change image.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);